# Android Widget - Permission Denial

Tags: java, android, widget, android-permission

Estou tendo um problema de permissão que fugiu um pouco dos meus conhecimentos.
Dentro de um widget inseri um botão, que ao apertar recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> 04-13 14:10:44.340: E/DatabaseUtils(2362): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires **android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL**
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.370: E/DatabaseUtils(2362):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.370: E/DatabaseUtils(2362):     at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.370: E/DatabaseUtils(2362):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.370: E/DatabaseUtils(2362):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.370: E/DatabaseUtils(2362):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.370: E/DatabaseUtils(2362):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.370: E/DatabaseUtils(2362):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>
> 04-13 14:28:19.570: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2362): **ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!**

Funciona da seguinte forma:
Na classe do Widget (WidgetApp), no método onUpdate() tenho as seguintes linhas (**linhas em questão do problema**):

```
rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
Intent intentSync = new Intent(context, Sincroniza.class);
PendingIntent piS = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentSync, 0);        
rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_Btn_Atualiza, piS);
```

Na Activity Sincroniza tenho as seguintes linhas no método onCreate():

```
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intentService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AWidget.class);
            startService(intentService);
            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Widget Atualizado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            
        }
    });


    finish();
```

Ou seja, sobre as linhas acima: carrega a Activity, faz a chamada do service e fecha. Para quem trabalha com Widget sabe que o **setOnClickPendingIntent()** faz necessário chamado de uma PendingIntent.

Sobre a permissão **INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL**, nem adianta colocar o uses permissions, primeiro que nem fica na lista padrão do sdk, tem que inserir manual. Segundo que não adianta.

Resumindo, meu widget (que é baseado em BroadcastReceiver por padrão do Android), carrega um RemoteViews do layout e insere um evento do botão desejado (setOnClickPendingIntent). Esse evento carrega uma Activity, que executa um Service e em seguida fecha o mesmo Activity.

***INTERESSANTE: Tudo isso funciona normal por um período, depois de alguns minutos para de funcionar.***

**DETALHE: A classe Service AWidget.class utilizo em um AlarmManager e funciona sem problemas.**

Answer (score 2):

Olá, pesquisei um pouco e encontrei várias pessoas com o mesmo problema que o seu pedindo esclarecimentos no *stackoverflow.com*, onde a melhor resposta pode ser acessada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756727/what-do-i-do-about-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full/19756762#19756762). Ela diz o seguinte:

`android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` é uma permissão de nível de assinatura. Seu aplicativo não será capaz de usá-la antes que ele tenha a mesma assinatura que o sistema.

O que não é possível a menos que você seja o criador do sistema ou consiga um certificado para o seu aplicativo.

Em outras palavras, isso **infelizmente está fora dos limites para a maioria dos desenvolvedores.**

Seguem outros links que podem ser úteis:

- [Permission Denial: this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578474/permission-denial-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full)
- [Permission Denial: startActivity asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179159/permission-denial-startactivity-asks-to-run-as-user-2-but-is-calling-from-user)
- [Interact Across Users permission side effect on su (Android 4.2.1)](http://insitusec.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/interact-across-users-permission-side.html)

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida pergunte nos comentários.